# 'Does not recognise [field] as a valid field name or expression' in crosstab

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table

I have a working query which I have attempted to turn into a crosstab, and it has then failed.

The original query looks at two tables to create a cumulative sum of deliveries before a date, split out by product. I then want to crosstab so the products are each a column (the list of products may vary so hard-coding this isn't an option).

The error that comes up is

> The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 'MonthEnds.product_id' as a valid field name or expression

I know `MonthEnds.product_id`, it's a key part of the subquery. What could be making it invalid?
I already saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054823/the-microsoft-access-database-engine-does-not-recognize-tbl-assignmentdetails) and checked through for ambiguities but I always specify my table names as standard, I'm sure it's not an ambiguity issue.

Broken code:

```
TRANSFORM 
    Sum(
        (
            SELECT
                    SUM(M.product_qty)
            FROM
                    T_StockMoves M
            WHERE
                    M.product_id     = MonthEnds.product_id
            AND     M.delivery_date  <= MonthEnds.D
            AND     M.state_priority >= InputFilter
        )+Nz(
            (
                SELECT
                        SUM(S.qty)
                FROM
                        T_SalesLines S
                WHERE
                        S.product_id     = MonthEnds.product_id
                AND     S.Delivery_date  <= MonthEnds.D
                AND     S.State_priority >= Inputfilter
            ),0
        )
    ) AS Qty
SELECT
        MonthEnds.D                  AS MonthEnd,
        MonthEnds.D-T_Products.delay AS Order_By
FROM
        (
            SELECT
                    AllDates.product_id,
                    DATESERIAL(YEAR(DateAdd("m", 1, AllDates.D)), MONTH(DateAdd("m", 1, AllDates.D)), 1) - 1 AS D
            FROM
                    (
                            SELECT
                                    StockMoves.product_id,
                                    StockMoves.Delivery_date AS D
                            FROM
                                    T_StockMoves StockMoves
                            
                            UNION
                            
                            SELECT
                                    SalesLines.product_id,
                                    SalesLines.Delivery_date
                            FROM
                                    T_SalesLines SalesLines
                    ) AS AllDates
        ) AS MonthEnds
INNER JOIN
        T_Products
ON
        MonthEnds.product_id = T_Products.id
GROUP BY
        MonthEnds.D,
        MonthEnds.D-T_Products.delay PIVOT T_Products.name;
```

The same code without the crosstab, which works:

```sql
SELECT
        MonthEnds.product_id   ,
        T_Products.name        ,
        MonthEnds.D                  AS MonthEnd,
        MonthEnds.D-T_Products.delay AS Order_By,
        (
                SELECT
                        SUM(M.product_qty)
                FROM
                        T_StockMoves M
                WHERE
                        M.product_id     = MonthEnds.product_id
                AND     M.delivery_date  <= MonthEnds.D
                AND     M.state_priority >= InputFilter
        ) + NZ(
            (
                SELECT
                        SUM(S.qty)
                FROM
                        T_SalesLines S
                WHERE
                        S.product_id     = MonthEnds.product_id
                AND     S.Delivery_date  <= MonthEnds.D
                AND     S.State_priority >= Inputfilter
            ),0
        ) AS Qty
FROM
        (
                SELECT
                        AllDates.product_id,
                        DATESERIAL(YEAR(DateAdd("m", 1, AllDates.D)), MONTH(DateAdd("m", 1, AllDates.D)), 1) - 1 AS D
                FROM
                        (
                                SELECT
                                        StockMoves.product_id,
                                        StockMoves.Delivery_date AS D
                                FROM
                                        T_StockMoves StockMoves
                                
                                UNION
                                
                                SELECT
                                        SalesLines.product_id,
                                        SalesLines.Delivery_date
                                FROM
                                        T_SalesLines SalesLines
                        ) AS AllDates
        ) AS MonthEnds
INNER JOIN
        T_Products
ON
        MonthEnds.product_id = T_Products.id;
```

Comment: I find it easier (and it may be the only way to get it to work) to split this up. Keep your working query. Then base the Crosstab query on that query, instead of building it from scratch (from tables and subqueries).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've tried that and it has made no difference.

Comment: The base query has a result column `product_id`. In the crosstab query you would only use `product_id`, not `MonthEnds.product_id`. Does that really give the same error?